# How to populate one text box value to another text boxes in angular6

Tags: angular

```js
seat1Modified(value): void {
    value.seat2 = value.seat1;
    value.seat3 = value.seat2;
  }
  seat2Modified(value): void {
    value.seat3 = value.seat2;  
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-1"> <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="vlaue.seat1" (ngModelChange)="seat1Modified(vlaue)"/> </div> <div class="col-md-1"> Year 2 seats </div> <div class="col-md-1"> <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="vlaue.seat2" (ngModelChange)="seat2Modified(vlaue)" /> </div> <div class="col-md-1"> Year 3 seats </div> <div class="col-md-1"> <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="vlaue.seat3" /> </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALVGI.jpg)

If enter 1st text box value, i need to populate 2nd text box and if i enter 2nd text box value populate 3rd text box

Year 2 seats  

   

 Year 3 seats

Comment: how did you? can you provide your code and any errors that you receive?

Comment: so far i tried with change event for text boxes

Comment: so whats the issue? you havent provided any code or an explanation as to what isnt working

Comment: seat1Modified(value): void {
    value.seat2 = value.seat1;
    value.seat3 = value.seat2;
  }
  seat2Modified(value): void {
    value.seat3 = value.seat2;
  }

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there wrapped in the code braces to it formats in a way that's readable. It's impossible to read code posted in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your have some typos in you variables names (`vlaue` should be `value` in your templates)

check this :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  value = {
    seat1: undefined,
    seat2: undefined,
    seat3: undefined,
  }
  seat1Modified(value): void {
    value.seat2 = value.seat1;
    value.seat3 = value.seat2;
  }
  seat2Modified(value): void {
    value.seat3 = value.seat2;  
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-1"> 
  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="value.seat1" (ngModelChange)="seat1Modified(value)"/>
</div> 

<div class="col-md-1"> Year 2 seats </div> 

<div class="col-md-1"> 
  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="value.seat2" (ngModelChange)="seat2Modified(value)" /> 
</div> 
<div class="col-md-1"> Year 3 seats </div> 
<div class="col-md-1"> <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="value.seat3" /> </div>
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mj74np)

Comment: is there any better way to achieve this functionality